# Custom DropDownList Multiple Items without aspx

Tags: c#, telerik, custom-controls, radcombobox

I have a custom `DropDownList` control built off of a Telerik `RadComoBox`. I'm currently trying to get this custom control to emulate another `RadComboBox` I have on another page that is capable of showing UserFullName, (Company) in the `RadComboBox` drop down by using the following aspx:

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbUsers" runat="server" Width="250px" DropDownWidth="300px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbUsers_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                         HighlightTemplatedItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Height="400px">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div>
                                Full Name (Company)
                            </div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullNameLastFirst") %></b>&nbsp;
                                (<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Company") %>)
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Is there anyway for me to imitate this in C# code behind for my custom control? It's a requirement that I not require any aspx besides the tag:

`<cc1:UserListBox ID="rcbUserTrained" runat="server" OnPreRender="rcbUserTrained_PreRender"/>`

Is this possible to do at the databind or render of the custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this awhile ago, basically I created a new class called `UserListBoxColumns` that inherits `ITemplate`. I defined my column structure there and bound the data and built it into my custom `radcombobox` by overrideing the `CreateChildControls()` method where I assigned the appropriate header/itemtemplate/footer into the comobox:

```
rcbUserList.HeaderTemplate = new UserListBoxColumns(ListItemType.Header);
rcbUserList.ItemTemplate = new UserListBoxColumns(ListItemType.Item);
rcbUserList.FooterTemplate = new UserListBoxColumns(ListItemType.Footer);
```

If you're interested email me and I can provide more details.